# TF Learn CNN example: How to add one more layer?

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

Considering [Text Classification Using Convolutional Neural Networks on Characters](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification_character_cnn.py) example:
I want to have three layers of convolution (instead of two in the original code). [Here is the modified code with three layers](https://github.com/amirj/dbpedia_cnn/blob/master/cnn_3layers.py#L69-L82). It seems that I have problems with shapes. Would you please consider the code and let me know what's wrong with it?

Comment: can you share the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `print(pool1)`, `print(pool2)`, and `print(pool3)` in lines 68, 83, and 90, respectively, you'll notice only the first two are printed:

```
Tensor("CNN_Layer1/transpose:0", shape=(?, 41, 10, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("CNN_Layer2/transpose:0", shape=(?, 11, 10, 1), dtype=float32)
```

And that's because you weren't careful with data dimension while creating new operations. Take a look at the changes in the dimensionality of your network:

```
byte_list output shape = (?, 100, 256, 1)
# apply 10x conv1 filters of size (20,256)
conv1 output shape = (?, 81, 1, 10)
# apply max_pooling of size 4 and stride 2 + transpose filter dimension
pool1 output shape = (?, 41, 10, 1)
# apply 10x conv2 filters of size (20,10)
conv2 output shape = (?, 22, 1, 10)
# apply max_pooling of size 4 and stride 2 + transpose filter dimension
pool2 output shape = (?, 11, 10, 1)
```

Then you try to apply 10x conv2 filters of size `(20,10)`, but your tensor has shape `(?, 11, 10, 1)`. If this operation were succesfully applied to it, its shape would be `(?, -8, 1, 10)`, but negative dimensions are impossible. Therefore, the problem comes from line 86.

There are multiple ways to approach this, and all of them involve either changing the filter sizes and/or network architecture. Just try writing down these dimensions to keep track of what is going on, and you should be able to figure out how to do it. :-)